# Export PDF from Excelsheet in Landscape format without blank space

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, shrink

need a solution for my misery. This following Code works, but the Problem is it Shows me the blank space as a full site. I would like to know if its possible to "shrink" that?

***The shrinking should start @ Column "F"***

This is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim mySheets As Variant, sh

    mySheets = Array("Tabelle1")
    For Each sh In mySheets
        Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

    Next
    Range("A1:CR33").Select

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\export.pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    End If
End Sub
```

For Illustration here the Pictures.
This is what i get:  http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=e31421-1438765650.jpg

This is what i want:  http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=a9f566-1438765707.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim mySheets As Variant, sh

```
mySheets = Array("Tabelle1")
For Each sh In mySheets
    Sheets(sh).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

Next

For Each the_cell In Range("A1:A33")
    If the_cell.Value = "" Then
        the_cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next the_cell

Range("A1:CR33").Select


Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\export.pdf", _
    quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Range("A1:A33").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Essentially, I've added a loop - which will hide the cells before the first filled in row (and unhide after)

Hope that this works for you as intended

Comment: Hey Trum, unfortunately not. Its the same Output, here a screenshot:
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=612b8d-1438773890.jpg
Its not hiding the blank space.

Comment: Is the white space true blank? If its spaces or something it may not work. It exported correctly using the code when I tried it.